# How to fix the major issue in SonarQube "needlessly boxes a boolean constant"

Tags: java, sonarqube, boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I have this method in my project:

```
private static boolean isNAND(boolean value1, boolean value2) {
        return value1 ? !value2 : Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

but I got this major issue in SonarQube that I don't know how to solve it:

```
Method io.clouding.bendiciones.buenas.noches.Operador.isNAND(boolean, boolean) needlessly boxes a boolean constant
```

Comment: I suppose it's because Boolean.TRUE returns a Boolean instead of a boolean. Try returning true instead of Boolean.TRUE

Comment: true, but then I will got a "Remove the literal "true" boolean value. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you should either do the following:

a. Either change the return type to Boolean object type. This would depend further on what you do with object of type `Boolean`.
b. Change the return value from `return value1 ? !value2 : Boolean.TRUE;` to `return value1 ? !value2 : true;` or `return value1 ? !value2 : !value1;`

This can be simplified further. If i look at the table of return values, then i see this:

```
value1 value2 result
T        F     T
F        T     T
T        T     F
F        F     T
```

Which means it's equivalent to `return !(value1 & value2)`

This is because while returning value, you are going to convert object of type `Boolean` to primitive boolean.

Comment: true, but then I will got a "Remove the literal "true" boolean value. "

Comment: Then better you should change it to `return value1 ? !value2 : !value1;`

Answer (score 0):

That :        `return value1 ? !value2 : Boolean.TRUE;`

means return `true`  if `value1` is `false` and return `!value2` if `value1` is `true`.

It may be simplified as : `return !value1 || !value2;` and it uses no boolean wrappers.